# Restriction/lock down all Post/Delete Rest API end points based on the condition

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am looking options to secure my rest end points based on the condition. In our current app all users are assigned to various tasks. User can perform different actions on tasks like create new notes, update notes, delete notes, update task information etc. User should be restricted  only to the tasks that are assigned to him/her rest of tasks remaining in the apps should be readonly. User is not allowed to perform any of the updates to the tasks that are not assigned to him.

Is there any universal annotation approach to check the status and lock down all rest post end points.

Answer (score 1):

Extended Configuration class from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter can have option to use the HTTP Basic authentication to protect the REST endpoints

```
        http
                //HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/notes/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/notes").hasRole("AUTHOR")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/notes/**").hasRole("AUTHOR")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/notes/**").hasRole("AUTHOR")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/notes/**").hasRole("AUTHOR")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }
```